# Text that is strikethrough and red in Rmarkdown rendered to PDF

Tags: colors, latex, r-markdown, markdown

For revisions to a paper written in Rmarkdown, I would like to have text that is red (indicating modification) and strikethrough (indicating deletion), but I cannot figure out how to get both at the same time. I can get strike through using Markdown syntax:

```markdown
~~Strikethrough~~
```

And I can get red text using Latex:

```markdown
\textcolor{red}{Red text}
```

But combining the two does not work. The following:

```markdown
~~\textcolor{red}{Will produce an error}~~
```

produces the error `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color {red}.`, presumably because the color `red` is not defined inside the `\st` command used for strike through.

Combining the two in the opposite order just treats the tildas (`~`) as a Latex request for extra spacing:

```markdown
\textcolor{red}{~~Will be indented~~}
```

How would I combine these two commands?

A minimalist Rmmarkdown document demonstrating the problem would be:

```markdown
---
output: pdf_document
---

~~Strikethrough~~

\textcolor{red}{Red text}

\textcolor{red}{~~Not strikethrough, the tildas produce spacing~~}


~~\textcolor{red}{Causes an error}~~
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is to use pure Latex instead of mixing markdown for strike through and Latex for coloring text. A working example is:

```markdown
---
output: pdf_document
---

~~Strikethrough~~

\textcolor{red}{Red text}

\textcolor{red}{~~Not strikethrough, the tildas produce spacing~~}

\textcolor{red}{\st{Red text with strike through}}
```

Comment: If you frequently use the combination of red and strike through text, then you could create a macro which will so both at once.